# How to post multipart in react native with RNFetchBlob or any other way

Tags: react-native, blob, fetch, multipart

i'm trying to send multipart request in react native. I tried many ways but none of them worked. Please check this example.

```
const data ={
        "person": this.state.person,
        "email": this.state.email,
        "password":this.state.password,
        "confirmPassword":this.state.confirmPassword,
        "otp": {
            "secret":this.state.otp
        },
    }



  RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', '${server}api/user-registration/register', {
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',
    }, [
        {
            name:"data",data:JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    ]).then((resp) => {
       console.log(resp)
    }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
    })
```

I'm getting 415 as response. Looks like it's not put multipart/form-data in the Headers.

I've already tried that with Reactjs and it's totally working.
This is an example in Reactjs.

```
  const eventData = new FormData();
eventData.append('data', new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)], { type: "application/json" }));

axios.post('${server}api/user-registration/register',eventData,{headers:{}})
```

Can anybody see any issue on RNFetchBlob code?

Answer (score 0):

> Use like this for normal text

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

> Use like this code for file

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('img', { name: 'img.jpg', type: 'image/jpg', uri: 'url for image or video' });
```

> Then normally call API with this or your own method

```
fetch('url', {
   method: 'post',
   body
}).then(a=>a.json()).then(() => {
   *code what you want*
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', 'your serviceUrl', {
        Authorization: "Bearer "+token,        
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      }, [
        { name: 'file', filename: 'image.png', type: 'image/png', data: JSON.stringify(RNFetchBlob.wrap(Imageuri))}])then((resp) => {
          //response body         
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('error---------', err)
          // ...
        })
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an library called `axios`.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.set("field1", field1_value);
```

and make a Post Request using `axios`:

```
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "<put-your-url-here>",
    data: formData,
    config: {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
        }
    }
}).then(response=>handler).catch(error=>errorHandler);
```

Here, `handler` is a function which takes response as input and processes it, and `errorHandler` is a function which takes the error and handles it.